# Kubernetes shared persistent volume between pods results in no file events

Tags: java, kubernetes, glusterfs, watchservice, persistent-volume-claims

I have 2 pods that use the same pvc to mount a pv so that they can share files through the mounted directory. Pod A has a Java Application that watches for new files (using java.nio.file.WatchService) in the mounted directory, but if pod B creates/renames/moves/etc. a file to this directory, it shows up on the volume and in pod A but doesn't fire an according event. When I rename or do anything with the file in pod A it gets recognized directly.
The storage system is gluster-fs on a local kubernetes cluster.

Comment: Can you write more about what storage system using? Local disks or some cloud provider storage?

Comment: We're using gluster fs with local disks

Comment: Looks related to GlusterFS? https://lists.gluster.org/pipermail/gluster-users/2014-October/019236.html

Comment: Could be the case, I will look into it, thank you

Answer (score 4):

The reason for this behavior is that the Java WatchService can't ensure that file events are correctly generated when using a volume through a **bind mount**.

This article goes in great depth to why this is the case: https://blog.arkey.fr/2019/09/13/watchservice-and-bind-mount/

The simplest solution to this problem is to check for new files periodically.